# Creation of view with multiple subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm experiencing a little problem concerning a view.
I've learned most SQL things on my own, but this one is a bit too much for the moment, but if any has a fix, could you please add a small explanation or link to it so I can learn it without copy/pasting a solution.

Here is my query:

```
CREATE VIEW [HMVIEW] AS
SELECT (select testid
from Alert, Action 
where alert.ID = Action.alertId) as col1,
select (SELECT SUBSTRING(Action.action, 2, CHARINDEX(' ', action.action) - 1)
from action)) as col2;
```

it errors on the creat view as it says it has to be the only statement in the batch, but the second select (for col2) is the main reason. It works when only taking col1 but I need a view of the 2 columns together.

For future people who might end up reading this: I forgot to add that the columns should join together. I want the col1 (a testId) to have the right actions to it. 
For example: 0001|stoptestbyid

Thanks in advance & with kind regards,

David Vandenbroucke

Comment: Could you give some sample data and a sample result? I'm having trouble visualizing what exactly you'd want the view to return.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: The structure of your select statement looks a bit off - you could simplify it down into 'non data' to see what i mean.   "Select (select 1), select (select 1)"  - here i substituted the columns you're actually trying to select with 1, even as a base query(non-view) such a statement does not work

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag because this is SQL Server syntax.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson well basically in col1 it'll be showing a bunch of numbers, and the col2 will show which action will happen (the numbers in col1 are testID's) for example: 0001 stoptestbyid. I'll have to write thme in a txt file like stoptestbyid 0001 which will be executed by an external program. But after taking a short break, I think I should add a join into it, I'm seeing some flaws in my thinking method I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your query:

```
SELECT (select testid
        from Alert, Action 
        where alert.ID = Action.alertId
       ) as col1,
select (SELECT SUBSTRING(Action.action, 2, CHARINDEX(' ', action.action) - 1)
from action)) as col2;
```

The first `select` is probably going to return more than one row -- that is one error.  The second select is just dangling out there.  You could fix this as:

```
SELECT (select testid
        from Alert, Action 
        where alert.ID = Action.alertId
       ) as col1,
       (SELECT SUBSTRING(Action.action, 2, CHARINDEX(' ', action.action) - 1)
        from action) as col2;
```

But, in all likelihood, you want:

```
select testid, SUBSTRING(Action.action, 2, CHARINDEX(' ', action.action) - 1) as col2
from Alert join
     Action 
     on alert.ID = Action.alertId;
```

Comment: Ah, you're really fast one :)

Comment: ah yes, what you said is correct, I overlooked the fact I needed a join to merge them together, thank you, i'll try to work it out! It works the last one with the join, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You are defining column alias to subquery in select statement, so you only need one select keyword. You need to delete the other select keyword. So that two subquerys are representing two columns with the alias `col1` and `col2`. See example below:

```
CREATE VIEW [HMVIEW] AS
SELECT (select testid
from Alert, Action 
where alert.ID = Action.alertId) as col1,
(SELECT SUBSTRING(Action.action, 2, CHARINDEX(' ', action.action) - 1)
from action) as col2;
```

Comment: In my given question this would've been a correct answer, but I realized I didn't give enough information. Sorry for that, it should merge the 2 collums like col1 showing the testId's and col2 the according actions that should be taken to those test id's